# Azure need to find Top searched phrase

Tags: azure, azure-cognitive-search

I have a web application with a search tool in it, so I need to find most used searched phrase in azure(my allocation is in MVC), any idea how to do in azure like any tool which does this job.

e.g Users who have viewed or searched contact Names like Jen adams, Michael and so on ...then there should be a report which provides details like Jen adams most viewed/searched contact name followed by someone and so on in a list.

Is application insights useful for this ? 
Please let me know any links with step by step instructions.

Comment: What do you mean by `most used searched phrase in azure`? Please update your question and provide more details there. It is not really clear as to what you're looking for.

Comment: I have edited my question hope that is more understandable.